# FB is not defined, yet Javascript code runs smoothly

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've only started Javascript a few days ago, so this question might seem basic.
I've written some Javascript code to interact with the Facebook API.

The goal is to display all the pages managed by a user when he logs in via a Facebook login button.

The code seems to work as it does what it's supposed to do.

However, the console gives me the error "FB is not defined".

I've read all the other questions about this error and it seems to be linked to the asynchronous loading of the SDK, but i can't seem to figure this out.

How come i still get this error?

******EDIT 07/07/2017*******
Google Chrome's console gives me the "FB is not defined error" at the FB.getLoginStatus line of this portion of code:

```
function checkLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            getPagesList();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('pageslist').style.display = 'none'; //Hides the div when people are not connected
            document.getElementById('pagestatistics').style.display = 'none'; //Hides the div when people are not connected
        }
    });
}
```

It also points to the following part, which seems to be the issue since, when i remove it from the code, the error disappears:

```
//Here below, _5h0o is the class of the logout button
//This checks the login status AFTER the user clicks on logout thanks to setTimeout
    document.getElementsByClassName('_5h0o').onclick = setTimeout(function() {
        checkLoginStatus();
    }, 100);
```

Here is the full code:

```js
//Initialize Facebook SDK + Check Login Status
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>  
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   
   FB.init({
     appId      : 'xxxxxxxx',
     xfbml      : true,
     version    : 'v2.9'
   });
   
   checkLoginStatus();   
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>


//Facebook Login Button

<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="public_profile, read_insights, pages_show_list" data-width="300" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false" onlogin="checkLoginStatusAfterLogin()" onclick="checkLoginStatus()"></div>  

<script>
 //Checks login status after people click on the Facebook button (useful for logout event)
 function checkLoginStatus() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
    getPagesList();
   } else {
    document.getElementById('pageslist').style.display = 'none'; //Hides the div when people are not connected
   }
  });
 }
 
 //Checks login status after people log in via the Facebook button
 function checkLoginStatusAfterLogin() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
    getPagesList();
    document.getElementById('pageslist').style.display = 'inline-block';
   } else {
    checkLoginStatus();
   }
  });
 }
 
 //Here below, _5h0o is the class of the logout button
 //This checks the login status AFTER the user clicks on logout thanks to setTimeout
 document.getElementsByClassName('_5h0o').onclick = setTimeout(function() {
  checkLoginStatus();
 }, 100);
</script>


//Display the pages (in the form of clickable spans) for which the user has reading rights


<div id="pageslist"></div>

<script>
 function getPagesList() {
  FB.api('/me/accounts', {fields:'id, name'}, function(response){ 
   document.getElementById('pageslist').innerHTML = ''; //Makes sure the div is cleared before populating it with the list of pages
   for (i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('pageslist').innerHTML += '<span class=\"pageslistspan '+response.data[i].id+'\" onclick="showStatistics(this.classList[1])">'+response.data[i].id+' '+response.data[i].name+'</span>'+'<br>';
     
   }  
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you have included FB sdk where your js is not aware

Comment: @Volem What do you mean by "where your javascript is not aware?" The sdk still loads since the program runs.

Comment: _Where_ do you get that error, which line of code is it referring to?

Comment: @CBroe I edited my initial question with more information. I have found which part of the code generates the error, but I have no idea why. I would like to understand this issue so I don't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: `onlogin` on the login button is not a “normal” event handler; I think you might need to specify the function name only there, without the ()

Comment: @CBroe I don't think the problem comes from `onlogin` because it doesn't call the function checkLoginStatus. It calls checkLoginStatusAfterLogin. I had to write 2 separate functions because for the login, the status has to be checked after the user completes the login with his username and password. Whereas for the logout, the status has to be checked onclick.

Comment: Well that’s what you said where you get the error, in checkLoginStatusAfterLogin, right? Why do you have a click handler on the login button in the first place? Facebook provides the logic to deal with the user clicking on the button, you should not interfere with that. And why are you calling logout automatically with a timeout in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe Oops yeah my bad. I copied the wrong function. I wanted to point to checkLoginStatus. Sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: @CBroe I tried removing the () when i call the functions in the button with `onlogin` and `onclick` but it doesn't make a difference. And I cannot only specify the function `checkLoginStatus` there because I need to check if the user is already logged in when he arrives on the page. Otherwise, the list of his managed pages won't be displayed even if he was already logged in.

Comment: @CBroe I have a click handler because I want to show or hide the divs `pageslist` and `pagestatistics` depending on if the user is logged in or not. This is the simplest way I found with my limited Javascript knowledge. When i remove the part of the code that causes the error, the program runs smoothly without error. So that part is actually not necessary, it seems. The program is now working, but I would like to understand why that part of the code generates an error. This way, I won't reproduce the mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

Try encapsulating your getPagesList inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     getPagesList(){
      ...
     }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Volem. This answer might work but as nothing else in my code uses jQuery, i would like to have a solution in pure javascript.

Comment: To be more precise, Google Chrome console gives me the error on the part of the code where I define the checkLoginStatus function, and more specifically on the line with FB.getLoginStatus.

Comment: Ok so I played a bit around with the code and the problem comes from the following part... I just don't know why. "
 document.getElementsByClassName('_5h0o').onclick = setTimeout(function() {
  checkLoginStatus();
 }, 100);"